# Background Image Is Other Image Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image

I Have 2 PictureBox 
PictureBox1 = Snake 
PictureBox2 = Grass 
I Done give the Picturebox2 beside picturebox1 and I Want my Snake Background is Grass in PictureBox2, i done change the Back Color PictureBox1 to Transparent and it's not working

[image: This my Application]

My Snake Background is transparent
can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: some remarks: you have to enable transparency on the form too - guessing that you want to do some sprite animations you will soon find out that using picture-boxes is not a very good way to do it - you will want double buffering and stuff ...

Comment: If i change the transparent on the form, it's say 'Property Value is not valid' , so i must do what T_T ?

Comment: It works just fine, I can clearly see the form background.  Hmya, not what you want, you *actually* want layers of paint.  Well, that's easy too, just call DrawImage() twice in an event handler for the form's Paint event.  Two expensive controls replaced by two simple lines of code, always good.  Or use the form's BackgroundImage for the grass.  Or set the Parent property of the snake to the grass control.

Comment: @HansPassant i'm using VB.net, not C# and i can't use C# T_T